# Is there a museum in South Korea about defectors and refugees who escaped North Korea?

Tags: south-korea, museums, north-korea

I was just watching a History Channel documentary [on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6JOMvOwECo) called "Kingjongilia" about people who have managed to escape North Korea.

Having visited South Korea a bunch of times now, I realize I didn't notice any kind of museum on these people and their plight.  Googling for one now isn't helping much either.

**Is there such a museum somewhere in South Korea?**

Comment: As everything has to be prooved or documented, what would be an acceptable non-existence proof here? I am pretty sure thst there is no such a place, but if I post that, nobody will trust me

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure. How did you come to be pretty sure? Maybe this is a problem worth discussing on meta?

Comment: Indeed. The floor is open for discussion: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1208/proof-of-non-existence

Comment: @MarcelC.: This isn't Math.SE!  I don't think we need definitive proofs for all our answers.  If you have good reason to think that there is no such museum, then an answer explaining those reasons would certainly be helpful; I for one would upvote it.

Comment: @NateEldredge I know that this isn't Math.SE! But thanks for telling me! As I have already said here and elsewhere it is by definition impossible to prove non-exidtence. That's why I asked the question here to know what the acceptable standards are. If I claim that such a museum exists, I will immediately by required to give an address. The same will happen if I tell that such a thing does not exist. I will be required to "prove" it in a way or another. Nobody will trust my words. Why should they?

Comment: Is it impossible? Prove it. d-;

Comment: Did someone [contact the Ministry of Culture of South Korea](http://www.mcst.go.kr/english/contactus/contactus.jsp)? If somebody would know, then it would be them.

Comment: Not an answer as such, but a defector [recently did an AMA (ask me anything) on Reddit, which may be worth a read](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/18umza/i_am_a_recent_defector_from_north_korea_joined_by/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not have a positive answer to this question. I have been looking around the web for a few days now and I am almost sure there is no such museum. I have been through the [list of museums in South Korea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_museums_in_South_Korea) with the help of Google Translate but with no luck. There is not even one comment about such a museum in any website. I think I can safely say such a museum does NOT exist in South Korea.

Answer (score 9):

Specific to defectors, not really. I think that would aggravate things more then anything. While South Koreans are aware of the "struggle" of many of their Northern brethren, things like the Ministry of Unification look actively to bond both cultures rather then highlight the differences.

If you're looking for a glimpse of North Korean life you might want to check out the [Odu Mountain Unification Observatory](http://www.jmd.co.kr/) in Paju. It's a fairly straight forward trip from Seoul and actually has a multi-level gallery that showcases the lives of North Koreans, from their groceries, clothes to "models" of homes. Plus in the basement you can get North Korean made goods, including liquor.

While you're in Paju you can also visit the DMZ, check out the elaborate ceremonies and tension between a bunch of 20 year old soldiers.

Why not actually just visit North Korea? I'm not sure how it is post Kim Jong-Il, but if your Mandarin is decent you can call around some of the travel agents in Dandong that will arrange a visa for you. The visa prices are actually comparable to some other well traveled countries. (Assuming you aren't American). If you're Malay you don't even need a visa :-)